# Avoid apostrophe with regex with event or saving to file

Tags: c#, regex, events, replace, richtextbox

How to avoid writing into the richTextBox of saving into the file for apostrophe  " `’` " and " `'` "

I also tried replace:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path); 
text = text.Replace("’", "").Replace("'", "");
File.WriteAllText(path, text.ToLower());
```

But If file content is large program hangs with using in events. Also I have this `�` instead delete time after time.

So would be good to avoid writing of marks with writing or with saving into the file

Seems like I'm doing it wrong:

```
string toFile = String.Join(" ", richTextBox1.Lines); 
var pat1 = @"\s?(’|')\s?"; 
var out1 = Regex.Replace(toFile, pat1, "");
File.WriteAllText(path, out1.ToLower());
```

so this way i lost lines if text is pasted and got whole text in one string.

but want get this result, if insert is:

```
Could’ve
Couldn’t
Didn’t
Doesn’t
```

I want write it to the file like this:

```
couldve
couldnt
didnt
doesnt
```

Comment: Your code here _doesn't use_ your final modified output; it still just writes the contents of the rich text box, which isn't modified. You need `File.WriteAllText(path, outText);`

Comment: Your other problem, though, seems to be that you don't specify a text encoding. Text can be written to a file in many, many different ways. Read through this article, please: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Also note, I think the text retrieved from a rich text box doesn't use standard Windows CR+LF line breaks. You might want to look into that, too.

Comment: The question is oddly phrased but there are two good examples of what you want the outcome to be. You should simply switch `File.WriteAllLines(path, richTextBox1.Lines);` to `File.WriteAllLines(path, outText);` - Since `outText` is where you've saved your modified string. Voting to close this as a small typo and not an actual issue.

Comment: @ Torxed  hello, edited but need to keep lines with writings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog oFile = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();

oFile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
oFile.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
oFile.FilterIndex = 2 ;
oFile.RestoreDirectory = true ;

if(oFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string file = oFile.Filename;
    string tmp = file + ".tmp";

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(tmp)) 
        System.IO.File.Delete(tmp);

    using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file)) 
    using(System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(tmp, false, Encoding.ASCII ))
    {
        string line = null;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            sw.WriteLine(line.Replace("’", "").Replace("'", ""));
    } 

    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
    System.IO.File.Move(tmp,  file);
}
```

Comment: Won't fix the fact he's writing UTF16 text though.

Comment: Honestly, nikorio's problem seems to be a lack of understanding of encodings in general; this code will stop working correctly from the moment the text contains special characters. The asker should _know_ which encoding they prefer to write the text in, and they can only know that if they understand the concept of text encoding.

Comment: @Igor Quirino hello, something is wrong with `while (line = sr.ReadLine() != null)` or I doing it wrong, not sure, says cannot convert bool to string

Comment: Im sorry, try again.

Comment: @Igor Quirino I got two questions about this code, I have all files in  `%ProgramData% ` so I need somehow relocate this  `string tmp = file + ".tmp";` I have path for executable  and with first rewriting I got question mark `?` instead  merged space in place of apostrophe, so have add there `.Replace("?", "")` to avoid this, but how to be if I want keep question mark?

Comment: you have many files or only one file? you can use OpenFileDialog? or should be a FolderBrowseDialog?

Comment: Try again. You will open a file and save the same file without apostrophe characters, right?

Comment: ...Or you can enter on my gitter room... https://gitter.im/HelpCSharp/Lobby

Comment: @ Igor Quirino I guess needs some corrections but as answer yes it is